# Node.js application crash when call a loop of ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js

I am using express in my node.js backend

one of my web api is like this: (request is superagent here)

```
var request = require('superagent');
router.get('/p/:pid', function(req, res) {
    request
    .get('path/to/another/api/')
    .query({
        productId: req.params.pid
    })
    .end(function(err, resp) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }

        var pp = JSON.parse(resp.text);
        // do something to pp ...
        res.json(pp);
    });
});
```

this route works fine in normal,

but when I make a loop of ajax request to this route, the application crash...

some of my front-end code:

```
var request = require('superagent');
var arr = [
        100,
        101,
        102,
        103,
        104,
        105,
        106,
        107,
        108,
        109
    ];

    arr.forEach(function(item, index) {
        request
            .get('/p/' + item)
            .end(function(err, res) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    return;
                }
                console.log(res.text);
            });
    });
```

after my test, if the arr's length is more 3, it will crash...
[image]
what's wrong?

Comment: Is the exception thrown from the call to JSON.parse(resp.text)?

Comment: How about [`async`](https://github.com/caolan/async). I guess you are not waiting for `forEach` to finish..

Comment: I would try to wrap JSON.parse() with try-catch, and print out resp.text to the console in case of exception, for debugging

Comment: dang it, JSON.parse problem, the another api return something sucks.